# How do i get http links from excel data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to get all http links from this data.

```
<a class="l-link-w clearfix" data-target-weblink target="_blank" href='http://www.havenswift-hosting.co.uk/clients/link.php?id=17' data-company-item="visitwebsite" data-omniture="WL">
<a class="l-link-w clearfix" data-target-weblink target="_blank" href='https://www.rathosting.com/' data-company-item="visitwebsite" data-omniture="WL">
<a class="l-link-w clearfix" data-target-weblink target="_blank" href='http://www.glxwebhosting.co.uk/' data-company-item="visitwebsite" data-omniture="WL">
<a class="l-link-w clearfix" data-target-weblink target="_blank" href='http://www.immersivemedia.co.uk' data-company-item="visitwebsite" data-omniture="WL">
```

Comment: Its in a excel file, i have copy pasted the source code

Comment: You can use `SEARCH()` to find the "href='" then `SEARCH()` again to find the "'" at the end of the href attribute value.  Then use those two numbers with `MID()` to pull out the URL.

Comment: I just find easy way by replacing similar data by blank lol!

Comment: =MID(E23,SEARCH("href='",E23)+6,SEARCH("data",E23)-4)  works fine

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source above is in A1:

```
Dim source As String
source = Range("A1").Value

i = InStr(1, source, "http", vbBinaryCompare)
e = InStr(1, source, "data-company", vbBinaryCompare)

link = Mid(source, i, (e - i - 1))
MsgBox (link)
```

For multiple values you can make a loop that reads all the rows...just substitute some code for the Range("A1").Value above. Something like this:

```
      Dim numRows As Integer

      'Replace the A1 with the location where you want your data
      Dim sourceData As Range
      Set sourceData = Range("A1")

      'Replace the A15 to where you want the data
      Dim destData As Range
      Set destData = Range("A15")

      'Set this to the number of rows in the source data
      numRows = 4

      For k = 1 To numRows
        Dim source As String

        'Replace A1 with the cell of the first line of data
        source = sourceData.Offset(k, 0).Value

        i = InStr(1, source, "http", vbBinaryCompare)
        e = InStr(1, source, "data-company", vbBinaryCompare)

        If ((i > 0) And (e > 0)) Then
            link = Mid(source, i, (e - i - 1))
            destData.Offset(k, 0).Value = link
        End If


      Next k
```